# How could I reuse a shell channel in JSch

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I need to send some command to some devices repeatedly to get some results,

I use JSch to connect to the devices and send the commands to them, then parse the results,

I find every time send the commands, I need to create a new channel, and have to wait another one or two seconds for the former channel to be destroyed, then the program can create a new channel successfully.

I want to know is there any way that can reuse the shell channel?  so I don't need to create a new channel every time, and don't need to wait for the former channel to be destroyed.

my codes are like this:
create the session:

```
JSch jsch = new JSch();
session = jsch.getSession(userName, deviceIp, 22);
session.setPassword(password);
Properties config = new Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);
session.setServerAliveInterval(5000);
session.connect(60 * 1000);
```

create the channel (the thread need to sleep about 3 seconds to wait for the former channel to be destroyed)

```
Thread.sleep(3000);
channel = (ChannelShell)session.openChannel("shell");
ops = channel.getOutputStream();
ps = new PrintStream(ops, true);
channel.connect(60 * 1000);
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(channel.getInputStream()));
ps.println("command-1");
ps.println("command-2");
while ((current = in.readLine()) != null) {
    // parse the results
}
// close the channel
channel.disconnect()
```

EDIT:

1. I tried to send commands to the channel again after parse the results,but it doesn't work.
2. I use thread pool to send command to the devices, so after connect to the devices, I save the session into a static map, then I can retrieve the connection to every device

Comment: Are you trying to use the same channel from different threads? You may need to do some thread synchronization if you intend to do that. The overall flow of your application is not clear from the code you have provided. It would be useful to see how you manage your threads.

Comment: *"the thread need to sleep about 3 seconds to wait for the former channel to be destroyed"* - Why? Please explain.

Comment: Anyway, "shell" channel is not for automation, it's for implementing an interactive shell session. For automation, use ["exec" channel](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html). - And once you are using "shell" channel (now ignoring that it's wrong), I do not understand your problem at all. Why do you even close it? Just send new commands after you read output of previous ones. - Maybe you should show us more of your code to explain your problem better.

Comment: I tried to send commands to the channel again after parse the results,but it doesn't work.
I use thread pool to send commands to the devices, so after connect to the devices, I save the sessions into a static map, then I can retrieve the connection to every device. when using JSch, after create the session, every time you want to send commands you have to create a new channel

Comment: *"I tried to send commands to the channel again after parse the results,but it doesn't work"* - *"it doesn't work"* is not a problem description. Show us your code! - *"when using JSch, after create the session, every time you want to send commands you have to create a new channel"* - That's true for "exec" channel, but clearly nonsense for "shell" channel. - You still didn't explain the "3 seconds".